# how to colour objects without texturing in openGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I want to colour objects in openGL without using any textures. Preferrably I want to colour objects based on an integer colour code. What is the best way to do this(in java)?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to color a triangle. Traditionally, coloring primitives in OpenGL meant specifying one color for each vertex, which  would then be interpolated across the primitive. You could also specify color with a uniform variable that's read in the fragment shader. The first method is more flexible, but requires more data per vertex. Specifying the color via uniform is fine if all of your objects are the same color, but may require a large number of (probably slow) state changes for varying colors. The method you specified, using an integer color code, is somewhere in between the two.

Here's one way to create a vertex buffer object with a color per vertex (my apologies if any of the syntax is wrong, as I haven't written any Java for a long time, so I'm mostly converting this from C++):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
ArrayList<vertex> vertexData;
<.....fill vertex data.....>

struct GPUVertex{
    GLfloat position[4];
    GLfloat color[4];
}
ArrayList<GPUVertex> VBOData = new ArrayList<GPUVertex>(vertexData.size());

for(int i=0; i<vertexData.size(); i++){
    VBOData[i].position[0] = vertexData[i].x;
    VBOData[i].position[1] = vertexData[i].y;
    VBOData[i].position[2] = vertexData[i].z;
    VBOData[i].position[3] = 1.0;

    VBOData[i].color[*] = ...some color...
}

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOData.size()*sizeof(GPUVertex), &(VBOData[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Then, when you go to render, just make sure to call `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0/1)` and `glVertexAttribPointer(0/1, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 24, 0/12)` when you bind the VBO for drawing. Then, make sure to add an extra `layout(location=1) in vec3 vertColor` to the vertex shader, as well as a variable like `out vec4 fragColor` with which to pass the result to the fragment shader.

To adapt this method for integer color codes, you would change `GLfloat color[4]` in the `GPUVertex` structure to an integer color code, then change `glVertexAttribPointer(...)`, `layout(location=1)...`, and `out...fragColor` to match, as well as specifying a color table.